# Is there a way I can verify the orientation iOS is intending to move to before I return a YES or a NO in shouldAutorotate?

Tags: ios, objective-c

As of iOS 7, you need to use

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    return YES;
}
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}
```

Instead of

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
```

However, my game has some really messed up orientation settings, and I really liked the old method because it allowed me to do some tricky conditionals thanks to the parameter `interfaceOrientation`. Now I can't. Is there a way I can verify the orientation iOS is intending to move to before I return a `YES` or a `NO` in `shouldAutorotate`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this

UIDeviceOrientation orientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation]